# Using navigation to redirect pages with React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import ShopMens from './ShopMens';
import ShopWomens from './ShopWomens';



      
    
const CategoryButton = () => {

    

    return(

        <View style={styles.buttonCont}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('ShopMens')}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>SHOP MEN'S</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('ShopWomens')} >
            <Text style={styles.title}>SHOP WOMEN'S</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
              
              </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    
    buttonCont: {
        flexDirection:'row', 
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        width: '60%',
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginBottom: 10
        },

        title: {
            fontWeight:'bold'
        }
  });

  const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
      {
          CategoryButton: CategoryButton,
          ShopMens: ShopMens,
          ShopWomens: ShopWomens
          
      },
      {
          initialRouteName: 'CategoryButton'
      }
  )

 


    

export default createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

React Native Experts. I need help with the navigation between pages.
I have a Home page with Bottom Navigation with Icon that works perfectly fine.
Then on the same I have 2 TouchableOpacity Button that I need to redirect to another page when I press on it.
I separated those 2 buttons on another component called Category Button, on that component I'm trying to do the Stack navigation to redirect the button to another page, but I have an error saying that stack has already been declared. I don't know how to fix this as I'm following the navigation doc on React Native, and I don't know if I'm doing this right. Can someone help?

UPDATE : I was using react-navigation v4 and v5. I now switch everything to react navigation v4 but my navigation between page ShopMens and ShopWomens is still not working, I don't think I did set my stack in the right way

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import Home from './components/Home';


export default function App() {

 

  return (
 
      
 <View style={styles.container}>
 
  <Home />

  </View>   

);

 
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    textAlign: "center"
   
   
  },

  header:  {

    color: "lightgreen",
    textAlign: "center",
    marginTop: 50,
    fontSize: 50,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  }
});
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';



import Profile from './Profile';
import Cart from './Cart';
import Favourite from './Favourite';
import CategoryButton from './CategoryButton';



const Home = () => {


    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
              <Text style={styles.header}>GOLDEN SHOE</Text>

            <CategoryButton />
           
              <Image style={styles.logo} source={{uri:'https://www.vooberlin.com/media/image/cb/d0/3d/JS36105A-13190-001-JIL-SANDER-LEATHER-LOAFERS-BLACK-2.jpg'}}/>
             
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 2,
      
      
    },
  
    header:  {
  
      color: "lightgreen",
      textAlign: "center",
    
    
      marginTop: 50,
      fontSize: 60,
      fontWeight: "bold",
    },

    logo: {
        width: 450,
        height: 550,
    },
    
  });


const TabNavigator =  createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
    {

      Home: {
          screen:Home,
          navigationOptions: {
              tabBarLabel: 'Home',
              activeColor:'#000000',
              inactiveColor: 'grey',
              barStyle:{backgroundColor: 'white'},
              tabBarIcon:() =>(
                  <View>
                      <Icon
                         name={'home'}
                         size={25}
                         style={{color:'#ff0000'}}
                      />
                  </View>
              )
          }

              
    
    },

    Profile: {
        screen:Profile,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
            activeColor:'#000000',
            inactiveColor: 'grey',
            barStyle:{backgroundColor: 'white'},
            tabBarIcon:() =>(
                <View>
                    <Icon
                       name={'person'}
                       size={25}
                       style={{color:'#ff0000'}}
                    />
                </View>
            )
        }

    },

            
       
        Favourite: {
            screen:Favourite,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarLabel: 'Favourite',
                activeColor:'#000000',
                inactiveColor: 'grey',
                barStyle:{backgroundColor: 'white'},
                tabBarIcon:() =>(
                    <View>
                        <Icon
                           name={'favorite-border'}
                           size={25}
                           style={{color:'#ff0000'}}
                        />
                    </View>
                )
            }
},

Cart: {
    screen:Cart,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Cart',
        activeColor:'#000000',
        inactiveColor: 'grey',
        barStyle:{backgroundColor: 'white'},
        tabBarIcon:() =>(
            <View>
                <Icon
                   name={'shopping-cart'}
                   size={25}
                   style={{color:'#ff0000'}}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }

    
},

    }

);

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

Comment: You are mixing react-navigation v4 (`TabNavigator`) and v5 (`Stack`). Also you have a typo in `CategoryButton`: `navagation` instead of `navigation`.

Comment: Yes, now I correct the typo the error says that I'm trying use react-navigation v4 and v5

Comment: I now switch everything to react navigation v4 but my navigation between pages ShopMens and ShopWomens is still not working, I don't think I did set up my stack in the right way

Comment: You still have v5 imports in your `RootStack` file.